# In wso2 API monetization why subscriber will fill details regarding plan

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In wso2 API manager why subscriber will fill details reagarding plan. As mentioned in the [documntation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Enabling+Monetization+of+APIs), the user will login and fill the plan for consumption but why he'll decide the billing plan for the consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mistake in the docs. As per the screenshot, it's the admin user who's logging in at step 7, but not the newly created user.

Comment: No, the user who will subscribe can set the billing plan. May be monetization for wso2 API manager is only for cloud users because the billing engine is the sample one. Looks like we have to use the sample code and reuse that to build for production set up.